# Command to use thresholds from ordered probit

Tags: r, stata

I am estimating an ordered probit (for those who only know probit I also added a very short explanation in the overleaf-hyperlink below). However my dependent variable is a percentage which has been categorised in eight percentage-groups. Meaning I know e.g. that category 1 means 0 percent, that category 2 means `0<y<5` etc. Consequently I know all of the thresholds `alpha` and could use them in [my likelihood function](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nkdkkfnbvnhx) (cf. equation (2) in this overleaf-link). Does somebody know a command for this in R or Stata or does such a command even exist?

Comment: Use package RStan; you can specify the probit thresholds as data rather than parameters. See mc-stan.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this with `oprobit` or `oglm` in Stata:

```
webuse nhanes2f
constraint 1 [cut1]_cons=-3
constraint 2 [cut2]_cons=-2 
constraint 3 [cut3]_cons=-1 
constraint 4 [cut4]_cons=0
oprobit health female black age c.age#c.age, constraint(1 2 3 4)
oglm health female black age c.age#c.age, link(probit) constraint(1 2 3 4)
```

Stata uses Pr(y=j|x)=Pr(cut_{j-1} < x'b + u <= cut_{j}), so this may not fit with your bins exactly. You might need to add/subtract c(mindouble) from the cut point to get what you want.

This is off-topic here, but I think the ordinal approach does not square with the observation that your "latent"  variable has a limited range with an unknown scale.

I would try `intreg` as a robustness check. It does not deal with the range issue, but the scale issue is not a problem in that setting.